# Finding a classroom transcript (for discourse analysis)

Tags: resource-request, discourse-analysis, applied-linguistics

I am writing an R package and am in need of a discourse data set (a classroom transcript) that I can publicly include. Quantitative data sets are a dime a dozen but getting a hold of a classroom (school) transcript that can be cited and reused is proving to be very difficult.

Does anyone know of a publicly available classroom transcript that I could use? Format does not matter (word, excel, handwritten, pdf etc).

*This question doesn't seem to full fir this stack exchange but I think it fits this stack exchange better than any others.  If it is inappropriate for here I apologize in advance.*

Comment: I think this is on topic, but my guess is that this would probably be nigh impossible because of issues involving getting consent from all of the students' families. Is there any reason it has to be from a (real) classroom? Perhaps you could work with a local school to  gather the data? Other guesses would be, look for materials directed at teachers -- perhaps they have examples of scenes in a classroom? -- or documentaries/films.

Comment: Yes I've run into this issue because of IRB approval but I don't understand why there are not complete transcripts available , as they are de-identified.  Many quantitative sets are available from classroom studies but not de-identified discourse.   The documentaries may be a valid approach I hadn't thought of.  I'd open this up to video/audio recordings of discourse (I'd prefer a complete lesson) and I'd transcribe.

Comment: The University of Michigan compiled and transcribed an audio corpus of classes, discussions, office hours, etc. -- all of the linguistic interaction contexts -- that took place on campus in the late 1990s. It's called [MICASE](https://lsa.umich.edu/eli/language-resources/micase-micusp.html) -- The Michigan Corpus of Academic Spoken English.

Comment: The twelfth text in the [Santa Barbara Corpus of Spoken American English](https://www.linguistics.ucsb.edu/research/santa-barbara-corpus#SBC001) is a classroom transcript as well.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for the search for such kind of resources is the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu). Alas, a naive search for "classroom transcript" gives only five hits at the time of this writing, and all the resources seem to be under some non-free licence. Try some variation in the search terms to find a suitable transcript.